# Casting std::complex<double> as double

Tags: c++

I want to extract the real part of a `std::complex<double>` as a `double`.

```
std::complex<double> c = 1.0;
double *d = reinterpret_cast<double*>(c);  // Want this to be = 1.0
```

The following gives an error `invalid cast from type 'std::complex<double>' to type 'double*'`. Is there an example on how to do this?

Comment: Why are you making `d` a *pointer*? Just `double d = c.real();` will surely do the trick.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real

Answer (score 2):

`double d = c.real();`

Best read the documentation of std::complex before continuing to use it:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

Comment: One more thing. C++ is a great language with a lot tools: Spoons, forks, grenades, photon torpedos. Unfortunately these tools have no warnings on them.  `reinterpret_cast<Value>` is a very dangerous, very dark, magic spell that obliterates every type in sight and has the potential to call The Dark Lord himself.  
Humor aside: NEVER use `reinterpret_cast<Value>`, ever!  
Also, if you are a beginner, don't use pointers, i.e. don't write `double *something`. If you are tempted to do so, chances are you are mislead.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want a pointer to the real element of a std::complex but are trying to convert a complex object to a pointer. They are entirely different things. Reinterpret_cast is very limited without UB but the standard makes an exception for `std::complex` Check the dox as @Hajo suggests.

From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

> For any pointer to an element of an array of complex named p and
> any valid array index i, reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i] is the real part
> of the complex number p[i], and ....

You can do this leaving off  `[]` as no the need to index into an array:

```
`double *d = reinterpret_cast<double*> (&c)`;
```

Caveat: While legal, if you change the value *d or c is changed you can get into UB. Generally a bad idea to do this.